# How to reference an algorithm created with algorithm2e using cleveref?

Tags: cleveref, algorithm2e

I am having issues figuring out how to reference an algorithm created with `algorithm2e`. For my figures, I use:

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{...}
  \caption{Test Caption.}
  \label{fig:test_label}
\end{figure}
```

and the reference with `\Cref{fig:test_label}` (using package `cleveref`). All works fine.

However, this does not seem to work with `algortihm2e`:

```
\begin{algorithm}
  \For{$b\gets 0$ \KwTo $B- 1$}{
      ...
  }
  \caption{Test Caption} 
  \label{alg:test_label}
\end{algorithm}
```

and then doing `\Cref{alg:test_label}` results in `??`. I would like to have something similar to `Figure 1`, i.e. `Algorithm 1` or `Alg. 1`.

How do I properly reference an algorithm created with `algorithm2e`?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Upon further inspection, I noticed that the numbers are actually showing, but the word `Algorithm` is missing: `?? 1`, `?? 2`,...

Comment: Did you compile your test document twice?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I compiled it twice.

Comment: @John Right, I ripped that out for the question here. Sry. Its back in there now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm puzzled by your claim that

> However, this does not seem to work with algortihm2e

For sure, the following minimalist test program

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{algorithm2e,cleveref}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \centering\dots \caption{Test a}\label{alg:a}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}
  \centering\dots \caption{Test b}\label{alg:b}
\end{algorithm}

\Cref{alg:b}, \cref{alg:a,alg:b}.
\end{document}
```

produces this result after compiling twice:

[image]

However, be sure to include the package `algorithm2e` **before** `cleveref`, otherwise you will end up with:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, it works. My issue was the order of including the two packages. I edited your answer to include this.

Comment: @Fabian - The general piece of advice is to load `cleveref` last.